# Merge two nested lists in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists:

```
x = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
y = [['a', 4], ['c', 6]]
```

I would like to keep only the common elements of the letters and combine the 2 lists into:

```
[['a', 1, 4], ['c', 3, 6]]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: you can do anything. What have you tried ?

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> x = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['c', 3]]
>>> y = [['a', 4], ['c', 6]]
>>> lazy = dict
>>> lazyx = lazy(x)
>>> lazyy = lazy(y)
>>> [[lazy, lazyx[lazy], lazyy[lazy]] for lazy in lazyx if lazy in lazyy]
[['a', 1, 4], ['c', 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested):

```
Z=[]
for x1, x2 in x:
    for y1, y2 in y:
        if x1 == y1:
            z.append([x1, x2, y2])
```

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is generally a lot better for these kinds of things.

```
z = {}
for key, val in x + y:
    z[key] = z.get(key, []) + [val]
print z #{'a': [1, 4], 'c': [3, 6], 'b': [2]}
print a["b"] #[2]
print a["c"] #[3, 6]
```