# Python merge single nested lists

Tags: python

I have a variable that holds lists

```
 s=[16, 29, 16] 
   [16, 16, 16]
```

I want to combine them like this

```
 combined = [16,16]
            [29,16]
            [16,16]
```

Comment: The world is irrational.  [Some (similar) questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299537/merge-two-nested-lists-in-python) get downvoted and some upvoted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#zip) function, like this

```
s = [[16, 29, 16], [16, 16, 16]]
print zip(*s)
# [(16, 16), (29, 16), (16, 16)]
```

If you want the output to be a list of lists, then you can simply do

```
print map(list, zip(*s))
# [[16, 16], [29, 16], [16, 16]]
```

Comment: @ i am getting error like this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 42, in <module>
    print zip(*score)
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
@thefourtheye

Comment: @user2243831 Please edit the question and show how `score` is defined

Comment: sorry i mentioned you wrong!i am looping a file through while loop and lists are created for every line in file @thefourtheye

Comment: @user2243831 mmm, I am going to say "Okay, So?"

Comment: so i am looking to sum them of every 1,2 etc.. once i extracted the list @thefourtheye

Comment: @user2243831 Please be specific when you ask questions. Edit your question to include all the relevant details to the question, sample input and expected output. Otherwise we both would be wasting our time.

Comment: i got it!i added a loop for it and then used the function above @thefourtheye